# Using 3D Rotation track animations in the AnimationPlayer in Godot

Tags: animation, godot, godot-4

Godot v4.1.2.stable

My goal is to make DirectionalLight3D rotate 360° around the scene, and in a second animation change the angle of rotation every 180 rotations between 75° and 30° on the X axis (a day night cycle with seaons and the world origin front view looking equitorial). I'd like to use as much engine functionality as possible and minimize scripts.

I've been looking for documentation for Godot on the 3D Rotation track and quaternions, which the rotation track forces you to use. Nothing has helped.

I haven't even been able to even get the directional light to rotate in the 3D Rotation track.

When you insert a key into the track, so long as the values are `x:0`, `y:0`, `z:0`, `W:1`, between 2 keys, a grey line will form. Change any value and the line breaks. I guess thats the anim track.

If the anim track is broken, I get the notif `AnimationPlayer: 'AnimationPlayer', Animation: ", 3D Rotation Track: 'daily solar motion' contains unnormalized Quaternion key.` from `editor/plugins/animation_player_editor_plugin.cpp:1610`. If the lines isnt broke, then the anim player runs without a notif, but theres no animation, since every key is set to 0 0 0 1. If both the DirectionalLight3D and the 1st anim key are set 0 0 0 1, but I change the 2nd key, the anim track breaks, I get the error notif.

Playing around with quaternions, it seems like I cant get 360° motion of on one axis if another has been changed.

How do I make the sun spin?
[image: The anim player and key inspector]

Comment: Which version of Godot are you using?

Comment: v4.1.2.stable, just added to the question